# How to write data to Google Glass

Tags: google-glass

I just started exploring Google Glass features. I am trying to make an application to record sensor data from Google Glass. I used the code that successfully runs in Android phone:

```
    public BufferedWriter file;
    private void startRecording(){
        //Prepare data storage
        File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

        String name = "Accelerometer_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".csv";
        File filename = new File(directory, name);
        try{
            file = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(Sensor sensor:sensors.values()){
            sensorManager.registerListener(sensorListener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
    }
```

After that, I used **file** to write sensor values to a csv file. It works fine on Android phone. But on Google Glass, it throws an exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Download/Accelerometer_1389803215753.csv: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Questions:

1. Does it need permission to write file?
2. Even if I can write file to Google Glass's data storage, how can I read that out? Do I have to root it in order to view files inside?
3. Is there any other ways to record sensor data from Google Glass? I am thinking of sending data over Bluetooth to Android device, but it seems more complicated.

Comment: have you tried maybe writing it to the database?

Comment: Sorry I didn't check thoroughly, I was missing uses-permission line in AndroidManifest.xml Now I think I am able to write data into Google Glass. But now, how can I read that data file out? Is it necessary to root Google Glass to see its data files?

Answer (score 0):

To read it back I did this and was able to get it to work

```
    BufferedReader reader;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                String line = null;
                String MutantString = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    MutantString += line;
                }

                t.setText(MutantString);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    return MutantString
```